# Java. Simple thread operation exchange

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am writing simple java Tcp client app. Connection is handled in another thread, and I am confused, how can I process some functions in main thread class? Should I use special static class? Or is there any "scheduler", which will proccess some actions between threads?

Comment: In *general*, by using shared objects and a correct synchronization strategy.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* in main object or thread */
synchronized (someObject) {
    someObject.wait();
}

/* in tcp connection thread / object */
synchronized (someObject) {
    someObject.notify();
}
```

Comment: That will cause the main thread to block until the connection thread calls `notify()`. If the main thread is a UI thread, this would make for a very poor user experience.

Comment: Well, he said his main thread class, I didn't take that as his ui, if there is one.  If it is, he should separate his TCP connection thread creation class into a third thread. Then, his UI thread won't be blocked.

Comment: Generally the entire reason for using a separate thread for TCP connections is to not block the main thread. Whether or not it is also the UI thread, your approach seems to defeat the entire purpose of having a separate thread for the network activity.

Comment: He may be conglomerating results.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Swing, you can use [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-) or [`SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(Runnable)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait-java.lang.Runnable-) to execute a `Runnable` on the event thread.

If you're running some other framework, it likely has its own API for injecting events into the UI thread. If you're creating a vanilla AWT app, for instance, you might be able to do this:

```
java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(event);
```

where `event` encapsulates the action you want to have happen on the UI thread. However, this could run afoul of permission requirements.